# How to adapt my viewmodel to implement dependancy injection swiftui (to later unit test)

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

Currently I have multiple ViewModels and after doing some reading and receiveing help on other posts I have been advised to implement dependancy injection in my class in order to unit test my logic.

However I am not sure how to adapt my following class to Dependancy injection, and I am not sure if i need to change my DataManager class too.

Here is one example of my ViewModels:

```
 class CalorieProgressViewModel: ObservableObject {


@Published var calorieProgress = [CalorieProgressEntity]()


init() {

}

//Creating the data
func addCalorieProgressData(id: UUID, calorieProgress: Double, fatProgress: Double, carbProgress: Double, proteinPogress: Double, created: Date) {
    CoreDataManager.shared.addCalorieProgressData(id: id, calorieProgress: calorieProgress, fatProgress: fatProgress, proteinProgress: proteinPogress, carbProgress: carbProgress, created: created){ (isAdded, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        } else {
            print("Data has been added from addCalorieProgress VM")
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I am just using the datamangerclass to add data to my Core-Data:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreData

class CoreDataManager {
    
    static let shared: CoreDataManager = {
        let appDelegate = AppDelegate.instance!
        let instance = CoreDataManager(managedObjectContext: appDelegate.persistanceContainer.viewContext)
        return instance
    }()
    
    var managedContext: NSManagedObjectContext
    
  private init(managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        managedContext = managedObjectContext
    }
}

//MARK:- CalorieTracker Insert/Update/Delete
extension CoreDataManager {

func addCalorieProgressData(id: UUID, calorieProgress: Double, fatProgress: Double, proteinProgress: Double, carbProgress: Double, created: Date, completionHandler: @escaping (_ succeed: Bool, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
        let calorieProgressEntity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "CalorieProgressEntity", into: managedContext) as? CalorieProgressEntity
        calorieProgressEntity?.id = id
        calorieProgressEntity?.calorieProgress = calorieProgress
        calorieProgressEntity?.fatProgress = fatProgress
        calorieProgressEntity?.proteinProgress = proteinProgress
        calorieProgressEntity?.carbProgress = carbProgress
        calorieProgressEntity?.created = created

       
        
        do {
            try managedContext.save()
            print("context saved for add calorieGoal")
            completionHandler(true, nil)
        } catch let error {
            completionHandler(false, error)
        }
    }
    
    func fetchCalorieProgressData(completionHandler: @escaping (_ succeed: Any?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
        var goals = [CalorieProgressEntity]()
        let calorieGoalRequest: NSFetchRequest<CalorieProgressEntity> = NSFetchRequest<CalorieProgressEntity>(entityName: "CalorieProgressEntity")
        
        do {
            goals = try managedContext.fetch(calorieGoalRequest)
            completionHandler(goals, nil)
        } catch let error {
            completionHandler(nil, error)
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Isn’t this a duplicate of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67193660/is-there-any-way-of-testing-core-data-viewmodel-with-unit-tests-or-any-sort-of-t)?

Answer (score -1):

There are different ways of dependency injection in Swift. You could do it via the `init()` and then pass your CoreDataManager when creating your ViewModel.

```
class CalorieProgressViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var calorieProgress = [CalorieProgressEntity]()
    let manager: CoreDataManager

    init(manager: CoreDataManager) {
        self.manager = manager
    }

    //Creating the data
    func addCalorieProgressData(id: UUID, calorieProgress: Double, fatProgress: Double, carbProgress: Double, proteinPogress: Double, created: Date) {
        //<< here don't use your singleton, instead use the manager injected via dependency injection
        manager.addCalorieProgressData(id: id, calorieProgress: calorieProgress, fatProgress: fatProgress, proteinProgress: proteinPogress, carbProgress: carbProgress, created: created){ (isAdded, error) in
        if let error = error {
```

Then when you create your ViewModel you will pass the CoreDataManager as parameter. Here you can use your Singleton.

I would recommend creating an protocol for CoreDataManager. Then you can easy pass your MockManager or the actual CoreDataManager into the ViewModel to test it later on.

```
protocol CoreDataManager {
    func addCalorieProgressData(id: UUID, calorieProgress: Double, fatProgress: Double, proteinProgress: Double, carbProgress: Double, created: Date, completionHandler: @escaping (_ succeed: Bool, _ error: Error?) -> Void)
}


class MainCoreDataManager: CoreDataManager {
    ... 

class MockCoreDataManager: CoreDataManager {
    ... mocked here
```